# refresh msflexgrid from another form

Tags: vb6

Working on some old code at the moment and a bit stuck

I have a main form that has a msflexgrid populated with data from SQL and on this form there is a button, which opens a modal form that allows me to enter data and save it to SQL (then closes the form).

The issue is the msflexgrid on the main form doesn't refresh after I save data from the modal, I need a way of automatically refreshing the msflexgrid after the modal form closes.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: On commit of changes in the modal form, you need to put the logic to write back the changes to the msflexgrid. Have you done that ? Can you please share the code written as part of commit of changes in the modal form ?

Comment: The commit button on the modal form basically just inserts the data SQL and unloads the form.  But I don't know how to write back to the main form.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a global structure and update it when the changes are committed in the modal form. After modal form is unloaded, control comes back to the command button click event in main form and there, you update the msflexgrid with the data available in the global structure. Like this, explicitly we need to update the msflexgrid and it is not refreshed automatically.

Comment: The problem is there can be several instances of the main form, so I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: what you you mean by "several instances of the main form". Can you please explain

Comment: The main form relates to a business the second form relates to a business contact for that business, there can be several instances of the main form/business open at any one time.  The issue with having a global is how would I know which business the global relates to when I commit in the modal form?

Comment: There may be several business records, but at a time, user deals with a single business contact. Right ?

Comment: A user can have more than one business at a single time, I can have 10+ business forms open if I wanted to, but each business form can only have 1 business contact form open at a time

Comment: When a contact is modified, you should be having the related business info maintained. On commit, the structure is updated and immediately the structure is used to update the flexigrid. So, there will not be any problem

Answer (score 0):

It just hit me that because the second form is a modal form it only return to the main form when the second form unloads, so I can just add the refresh function right after showing the second form, I knew I was doing something stupid :/

```
 Dim AddBusContact As New frmAddBusContact
 AddBusContact.SetBusID (clsThisForm.BusID)
 AddBusContact.Show (vbModal) 'code stops here until second form is unloaded 
 refreshgrid 'and I can just call the function that refreshes the grid here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one more idea. If the modal form allows the user to cancel action, or to give up what started to do, probably it is better to trigger the grid refresh function before the modal form unloads and only if changes have been made...